# How to find the locus of$ P$?

Tags: geometry, circles, tangent-line, locus

Two tangents are drawn from a point $P$ ***to*** the circle $x^2+y^2=1$. If the tangents make an intercept of $2$ on the line $x-1=0$ , then locus of $P$ is?
$A)$ Parabola
$B)$ Pair Of lines
$C)$ Circle
$D)$ Straight Line

What i did was to assume two tangents from point $P$ as $$y=mx \pm \sqrt{m^2+1}$$

and equate it with $x=1$. Sure it gives a value but how do i decide the ordinate then? Should I use symmetry or there is a better sophisticated method for this one?

Comment: You'l get value of m from given stuffs and then assume P(h,k) and then substitute ( h,k) in $x^2+y^2=1$

Comment: @ItiShree I can't seem to solve it. I'm getting $m^2=-1$ which makes no sense

Comment: Did you mean “Two tangents are drawn from a point $P$ *to* the circle.,..?” There’s only one tangent to a point *on* a circle.

Comment: There is an external point $P$ from where we are drawing the tangent @amd

Comment: That’s not what you wrote, though. Now, please explain what you mean by “an intercept ot 2.”

Comment: I wrote that only. @ amd. As far as "intercept of 2" is concerned. I think it's equivalent to the length intercepted by the tangents upon intersection with $x=1$. Although even I'm not sure about this part.

Comment: By speculative inspection, the locus of $P$ includes as limit points the points $(0,\pm2)$ and $(\pm \infty, 0)\,$, which eliminates all options but *B)* and would leave the pair of lines $y=\pm1$ as candidates.

Comment: @dixv sorry to say but ans given is parabola. Do you have a better logic to support your option?

Comment: @TheDeadLegend If I had one fully worked out, I would have posted it as an answer ;-) I don't see a "nice" geometric solution offhand, and I am not all that tempted to carry out the analytic one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let $A$ and $B$ be points on $x=1$ such that $|\overline{AB}| = 2$. With $R$ the point where $x=1$ meets the circle, define $\alpha := \angle ROA$ and $\beta := \angle ROB$. Let the "other" tangent from $A$ meet the circle at $S$; we see that $\angle ROS = 2\alpha$. Likewise, the "other" tangent from $B$ meets the circle at $T$ such that $\angle ROT = 2\beta$. Let these "other" tangents intersect at $P$, and note that $\overline{OP}$ bisects $\angle SOT$. Consequently, we can write
$$\begin{align}
P &= \sec(\alpha-\beta)\;\left( \cos(\alpha+\beta), \sin(\alpha+\beta) \right) \\
&= \left( \frac{\cos\alpha \cos\beta - \sin\alpha\sin\beta}{\cos\alpha\cos\beta + \sin\alpha \sin\beta}, \frac{\sin\alpha \cos\beta+\cos\alpha\sin\beta}{\cos\alpha\cos\beta + \sin\alpha \sin\beta} \right) \\
&=\left( \frac{1 - \tan\alpha\tan\beta}{1 + \tan\alpha \tan\beta}, \frac{\tan\alpha+\tan\beta}{1 + \tan\alpha \tan\beta} \right)
\end{align}$$

We can get the equation for the locus by eliminating $a := \tan\alpha$ and $b := \tan\beta$ from the system
$$x = \frac{1-a b}{1+ab} \qquad y = \frac{a+b}{1+ab}$$
subject to the "intercept condition"
$$a - b = 2$$

Without too much trouble, we arrive at the relation

> $$ 2( 1 + x ) = y^2$$

which describes a parabola. $\square$

Answer (score 2):

This is not a solution. The following figure is just my guess on the meaning of the question.

[image]